# bookmarklet: inserting text into textarea with js?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

What I am doing wrong?

```
 javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('textarea').innerHTML='inserted';
```

I want to create a bookmarklet to insert simple text to a textarea on a given webpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `value` property rather than `innerHTML` and make sure your code evaluates to `undefined`, which you can do by wrapping it in a function with no `return` statement. If you don't do this, the contents of the page will be replaced with whatever your code evaluates to (in this case, the string 'inserted').

```
javascript:(function() {document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value = 'inserted';})();
```

**Update 14 January 2012**

I failed to spot the fact that the original code was treating `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')` as a single element rather than the `NodeList` it is, so I've updated my code with `[0]`. @streetpc's answer explains this in more detail.

Comment: Downvoter: I imagine you downvoted this because I missed the fact that the original code was treating `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')` as a single element. That's fair enough, but leaving a comment to say so would have been helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Unlinke `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName` has an `s`at `Elements` because it returns an **<del>array</del> array-like NodeList** of the matching elements. So you'll have to access one of the elements first, let's say the first one for simplicity:

```
javascript:void((function(){document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value='inserted'})())
```

Also, as mentioned by others, `value` property rather than `innerHTML` here.

Comment: Actually `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array-like `NodeList` rather than an array, but your point is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wonders how to use the currently focused text field, use the following:

```
document.activeElement.value = "...";
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you have to use if this way:

for single element -> $('#element_id').html('your html here')
for all text areas -> $('textarea').val('your html here')

I have to confess that I`m not sure why it works this way but it works. And use rameworks, they will save you time and nerves.

Comment: @Antonio yes, you can load any scripts by appending script tags to the document. e.g. http://benalman.com/projects/run-jquery-code-bookmarklet/

Comment: @meleyal, Ithink it's quite risky: there could be a conflict of jQuery versions in case jQuery is already used in the page

Comment: @Antonio you could always run with `.noConflict()`: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/